# get unique values when concatenating two columns pyspark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below.

```
+---+-------------+------------+
| id|       device|       model|
+---+-------------+------------+
|  3|      mac pro|         mac|
|  1|       iphone|     iphone5|
|  1|android phone|     android|
|  1|   windows pc|     windows|
|  1|   spy camera|  spy camera|
|  2|             |      camera|
|  3|         cctv|        cctv|
|  2|       iphone|apple iphone|
|  3|   spy camera|            |
+---+-------------+------------+
```

I want to create a `column` by concatenating unique values in `device and model` columns for each `id`

I have done like below

First concatenated both `device and model` columns

```
df1 = df.select(col("id"), concat(col("model"), lit(","), col("device")).alias('con'))

+---+--------------------+
| id|                 con|
+---+--------------------+
|  3|         mac,mac pro|
|  1|      iphone5,iphone|
|  1|android,android p...|
|  1|  windows,windows pc|
|  1|spy camera,spy ca...|
|  2|             camera,|
|  3|           cctv,cctv|
|  2| apple iphone,iphone|
|  3|         ,spy camera|
+---+--------------------+
```

Then done a `groupBy` by `id`

```
df2 = df1.groupBy("id").agg(f.concat_ws(",", f.collect_set(df1.con)).alias('Group_con')


+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id|                                                                    Group_con|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1|iphone5,iphone,android,android phone,windows,windows pc,spy camera,spy camera|
|  2|                                                  camera,,apple iphone,iphone|
|  3|                                            mac,mac pro,cctv,cctv,,spy camera|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I am getting duplicate values in the result. How can I avoid populating duplicate values in the final data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `F.array()`, `F.explode()` and `F.collect_set()`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('con', F.explode(F.array('device', 'model')))   \
  .groupby('id').agg(F.collect_set('con').alias('Group_con')) \
  .show(3,0)

# +---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |id |Group_con                                                                 |
# +---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |3  |[cctv, mac pro, spy camera, mac]                                          |
# |1  |[windows pc, iphone5, windows, iphone, android phone, spy camera, android]|
# |2  |[apple iphone, camera, iphone]                                            |
# +---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(tested on spark version 2.2.1)

Comment: How can we remove the `array` to normal `string` in your answer

Comment: @Question_bank did you mean convert array to string or else?

Comment: convert array to string `[cctv, mac pro, spy camera, mac] ` to `cctv, mac pro, spy camera, mac `

Comment: for example: `@F.udf("string")`    [change line] 
`def join(s): return ', '.join(s) if type(s) is list else s`   [change line], then `df.select(join(F.col('Group_con'))`

Comment: @jxc I think you don't need `UDF` for this you can do like here `df1 = df.withColumn('con', F.explode(F.array('device', 'model'))).groupby('id').agg(F.concat_ws(",", F.collect_set('con')).alias('Group_con'))`

Comment: @user9367133, you are right! thank you for the cache-up.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the duplicates by using `collect_set` and a `udf` function as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t

def uniqueStringUdf(device, model):
    return ','.join(set(filter(bool, device + model)))

uniqueStringUdfCall = f.udf(uniqueStringUdf, t.StringType())

df.groupBy("id").agg(uniqueStringUdfCall(f.collect_set("device"), f.collect_set("model")).alias("con")).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |con                                                               |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|3  |spy camera,mac,mac pro,cctv                                       |
|1  |spy camera,windows,iphone5,windows pc,iphone,android phone,android|
|2  |camera,iphone,pple iphone                                         |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

where,
`device + model` is concatenation for two collected sets
`filter(bool, device + model)` is removing empty strings from concatenated list
`set(filter(bool, device + model))` removes the duplicate strings in the concatenated list
`','.join(set(filter(bool, device + model)))` concats all the elements of concatenated list to a comma separated string.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Got this error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"expression 'pythonUDF' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;"`

Comment: @Question_bank what is the spark version you are using? I tested the answer before I posted the answer though and there was no such issue. so recheck your codes. And if the issue still exists then you can apply the udf function after the aggregation in next step

Comment: My spark version is `1.6`

Comment: try as I told you then @Question_bank

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to be very helpful. But one solution I could think of is to check for the duplicate values in the column and then delete them by using their position/index.

Or

Split all values at comma "," list and remove all the duplicates by comparing each value. Or count() the occurrences of a value if its more than 1 the delete the all the duplicates other than the first one.

Sorry if this wasn't help. These are the 2 ways I could think of solving your problem.